# Get distinct records from 2 union sql statement

Tags: mysql, union, distinct-values

I would like to seek the advice of some sql experts.

I wrote sql statement for getting authors names from staff and alumni table. Some author's name will be in both tables. So the logic is if the author name is in staff, use that otherwise look for alumni table.

Here is my sql statement, seems fine but it is showing same author name from both staff and alumni table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AP.Author_name, P.people_id, P.Name, P.Journal_name, AP.Author_sortorder FROM  `Paper_Author` AS AP LEFT JOIN  `People` AS P ON ( AP.Author_id = P.people_id )  WHERE AP.Paper_id =3838

UNION  

SELECT DISTINCT AN.Author_name, N.People_id, N.Name, N.Journal_name, AN.Author_sortorder FROM  `Paper_Author` AS AN LEFT JOIN  `Alumni` AS N ON ( AN.Author_id = N.People_id )  WHERE AN.Paper_id =3838 ORDER BY Author_sortorder LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Result:

```
people_id--  Author_name--  Journal_name--  
    1        Name1              A1          
    2        Name2              B1          
    3        Name3              C1
    3        Name3              C1
    4        Name4              D
    4        Name4
```

Expected Result :

```
 people_id--  Author_name--  Journal_name--  
    1           Name1            A1          
    2           Name2            B1          
    3           Name3            C1
    4           Name4            D
```

Comment: Why don't you use `group by`?

Comment: Why does the last record of your current output not have a journal name?

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be solved by an additional select using the original result as a subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT AP.Author_name, P.people_id, P.Name, P.Journal_name, AP.Author_sortorder FROM  `Paper_Author` AS AP LEFT JOIN  `People` AS P ON ( AP.Author_id = P.people_id )  WHERE AP.Paper_id =3838

    UNION  

    SELECT DISTINCT AN.Author_name, N.People_id, N.Name, N.Journal_name, AN.Author_sortorder FROM  `Paper_Author` AS AN LEFT JOIN  `Alumni` AS N ON ( AN.Author_id = N.People_id )  WHERE AN.Paper_id =3838 ORDER BY Author_sortorder LIMIT 0 , 30
);
```

Comment: I think there needs to be an alias on that subselect and it needs to be referenced on the primary statement.

Comment: If this answer be correct, then it would imply that the information from the `People` and `Alumni` table is always the same for a given person.  Possible, but it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with this problem is that you might need information from either the `People` or `Alumni` tables.  We would like to just join to a single table containing the right information.  Much of the complexity of the below query is in creating a table which contains the right metadata for each person.

```
SELECT
    pa.Author_name,
    pa.Author_sortorder,
    t1.people_id,
    t1.Name,
    t1.Journal_name
FROM Paper_Author pa
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT people_id, Name, Journal_name, 0 AS source
    FROM People
    UNION ALL
    SELECT people_id, Name, Journal_name, 1
    FROM Alumni
) t1
    ON pa.Author_id = t1.people_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT people_id, MIN(source) AS source
    FROM
    (
        SELECT people_id, 0 AS source
        FROM People
        UNION ALL
        SELECT people_id, 1
        FROM Alumni
    ) t
    GROUP BY people_id
) t2
    ON t1.people_id = t2.people_id AND
       t1.source = t2.source
WHERE
    pa.Paper_id = 3838;
```